# Eclipse compiles correctly but shows error in 'Problems' view

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, linker, arduino

The console output is:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project Timertestnew ****

make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: AVR C++ Compiler
avr-g++ -I"G:\arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino" -DARDUINO=100 -Wall -Os -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fno-exceptions -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -c -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: Timertestnew.elf
Invoking: AVR C++ Linker
avr-gcc --cref -s -Os -o"Timertestnew.elf"  ./main.o   -lArduinoCore -lm -Wl,-Map,Timertestnew.map,--cref -L"C:\Users\Akhil\workspace\Timertestnew" -mmcu=atmega328p
Finished building target: Timertestnew.elf

Create Flash image (ihex format)
avr-objcopy -R .eeprom -O ihex Timertestnew.elf  "Timertestnew.hex"
Finished building: Timertestnew.hex

Invoking: Print Size
avr-size --format=avr --mcu=atmega328p Timertestnew.elf
AVR Memory Usage
----------------
Device: atmega328p

Program:     620 bytes (1.9% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:          9 bytes (0.4% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)


Finished building: sizedummy


**** Build Finished ****
```

The 'Problem' view output is:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'EEARH' could not be resolved    main.cpp    /Timertestnew   line 15 Semantic Error
```

Is it possible that eclipse ide is mistakenly showing this error while it compiles it fine?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete that problem marker from the problems view and rebuild your project (entirely, not just an incremental). If that fixes the issue, than it was simply an inconsistent state of the compiler.

However, if it does not fix the problem, then it is possible that the Eclipse editor uses a different parser (for content assist, etc.), that cannot handle something your compiler can. For this case, I would look around the C/C++ editor preferences related to errors, maybe it is turnable off (however, I don't program C/C++, so I cannot tell you what to look for).

Answer (score 2):

The avr-gcc compiler uses its `-mmcu` command line argument to determine which IO header file to include (and therefore symbolic register definition including the `EEARH` EEPROM high address register being reported). [Documentation here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__io.html).

Eclipse may not be aware of this 'backdoor' preprocessor symbol definition (as it probably is using a different compiler for problem detection). From the console output it looks like the IO header file you need is: `avr/iom328p.h` which is included when the `__AVR_ATmega328P__` preprocessor symbol is defined ([see here](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/trunk/avr-libc/include/avr/io.h?root=avr-libc&content-type=text/plain)). If you provide this symbol to Eclipse it should cause its compiler to pick up the correct file and define the relevant registers.